# Member is not adding in Group after Accept Request

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a simple `Blog Group App` in which users can make a group and post blogs in it, AND i build  feature of `join group by Request`, in which user have to send a join request and then Creator will approve it, BUT
When i click on accept_it then members is not adding in group.

models.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.ForeignKey(max_length=30,default='')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='group_member',blank=True)

class GroupRequest(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request_sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def accept_it(request,pk):
    group_request = get_object_or_404(Group,pk=pk)
    sent_request = get_object_or_404(GroupRequest,pk=pk)

    group_request.members.add(sent_request.request_sender)
    return redirect('home')

def DetailGroup(request,pk):
    data = Group.objects.get(pk=pk)

    context = {'data':data}
    return render(request,'Group_detail.html', context)
```

Group_detail.html

```
{% for requests in group_requests %}

{{ requests.request_sender }}<a href="{% url 'accept_it' requests.id %}">Accept it</a>


{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
    path('accept_it/<int:pk>/',views.accept_it,name='accept_it'),
```

When i click on Accept it then it redirects on another group BUT is is not adding the member in the group.

AND When i try `<a href="{% url 'accept_it' requests.request_sender.id %}">Accept it</a>` Then it is saying :-

> Page not found (404)

I have no idea, what am i doing wrong.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: I need to see urls.py

Comment: Updated the Question and Added `urls.py`

Comment: Sorry to bother you i kindly need to see the view which renders group_detail.html

Comment: Updated the Question

Comment: Why are you using `pk` on both `Group` and `GroupRequest`? Shouldn't it be only on `GroupRequest` and you get the `group` from `sent_request`?

Comment: Also you get the 404 because you used the request_sender's id, but you are using it against `Group` and `GroupRequest`. You need to use the `pk` properly

Comment: BUT what should i use instead of `pk` in `GroupRequest,pk=pk` ?

Comment: You need to decide on that. Say you decide to use `pk` as `GroupRequest`, then only use pk on `GroupRequest`

Comment: BUT I want to accept a particular `request` on a particular `Group`

Comment: Yes you can get the group from the request. I'll try to post an answer.

Comment: Your context equals to data therefore the template should be equal to: for requests in data not group requests

Comment: BUT how can i pass it in template ?

Comment: @YousefAlm, BUT how can i pass it in template ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decide what `pk` stands for in `accept_it(request,pk)`. Let's say you decided to use it for `GroupRequest`, then:

```
def accept_it(request,pk):
    group_request = get_object_or_404(GroupRequest, pk=pk)
    group_request.group.members.add(group_request.request_sender)
    return redirect('home')
```

Comment: It is saying **Page not found (404)**

Comment: You need to fix `DetailGroup` as well to use `GroupRequest` instead of `Group` in the template context.

Comment: BUT it will only render the `GroupRequest` BUT i will do some work on posts in future

Comment: Separate the page for the posts and the page for accepting group request then.